# Borde negro en fotos puestas como background-image en css

Tags: html, css

estoy haciendo que una imagen al pasar por encima el raton (hover) se cambie a otra con background-image y se me muestra un recuadro negro imposible de quitar (no propio de la imagen , ni del div ) .

¿Ideas para o bien hacerlo de otra manera o eliminar el recuadro negro ? ¡Gracias!

```css
#imagen{
  height: 450px;
  width: 450px;
  background-image: url('https://image.freepik.com/vector-gratis/fondo-lista-comprobacion-dibujada-mano_23-2148070711.jpg');
}
         
#imagen:hover {
  background-image: url('https://image.freepik.com/vector-gratis/fondo-grupo-confirmando-lista-comprobacion-gigante_23-2148084372.jpg');
  height: 450px;
  width: 450px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
   <div>
    <img id="imagen">
   </div>
  </body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el recuadro es porque la etiqueta img esta esperando una imagen , si pensas usar una imagen con el `background-image` simplemente puedes usar un div , te dejo la modificacion

```css
#imagen{
  height: 450px;
  width: 450px;
  background-image: url('https://image.freepik.com/vector-gratis/fondo-lista-comprobacion-dibujada-mano_23-2148070711.jpg');
  

}
      
#imagen:hover {
  background-image: url('https://image.freepik.com/vector-gratis/fondo-grupo-confirmando-lista-comprobacion-gigante_23-2148084372.jpg');
  height: 450px;
  width: 450px;
  border:none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
   <div id="imagen"></div>
     
   
  </body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Antes de nada. Se recomienda dejar los id para JS y las clases para CSS.

El motivo por el cual se mostraba el margen, es porque utilizas la tag img, que es para meter una imagen directamente desde HTML. Por la razón que sea, cuando lo manipulas desde CSS, te mete el recuadro.

Es posible que pase, porque la tag img crea un espacio de espera. Mirate esto (**https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp**) o MDN (Mozila Developer Network)

> The  tag creates a holding space for the referenced image.

Para que lo veas más claro, te dejo un ejemplo, que es tú código, más alguna cosilla que he agregado.

```css
.imageTest{
  height: 450px;
  width: 450px;
}

.imagen{
  height: 450px;
  width: 450px;
  background-image: url('https://image.freepik.com/vector-gratis/fondo-lista-comprobacion-dibujada-mano_23-2148070711.jpg');
}
         
.imagen:hover {
  background-image: url('https://image.freepik.com/vector-gratis/fondo-grupo-confirmando-lista-comprobacion-gigante_23-2148084372.jpg');
  height: 450px;
  width: 450px;
}
```

```html
<div class:"main">
<img class="imageTest">
<img src="https://image.freepik.com/vector-gratis/fondo-lista-comprobacion-dibujada-mano_23-2148070711.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="450" height="450"> 
<div class="imagen"></div>
</div>
```

Ojo, el código no está ordenado.

Comment: Dejar los ID para JS y las clases para CSS ???? Esa si no me la sabia, recuerda que tanto en JS y CSS puedes manipular los elementos del DOM como se te de la gana, puedes acceder a ellos a traves de su clase, su ID su etiqueta etc. Si tienes una documentación para sustentar eso que estas diciendo, me gustaria leerla tal vez es algo que desconozco aun. Cabe mencionar que hay otras fuentes mas fiables que la W3S.

Comment: Aquí no hablamos de JS mirate la pregunta y dime dónde está el JS, es CSS.

Comment: Tu mismo lo dices en tu respuesta, cito textualmente lo que escribiste: **Antes de nada. Se recomienda dejar los id para JS y las clases para CSS.**

Comment: Cabe mencionar que hay otras fuentes mas fiables que la W3S. de ahí que indico MDN. Puedes utilizar los id o clases tanto en CSS como en JS. Lee de nuevo, porque he puesto, "se recomienda" si no entiendes qué es una recomendación, pues lo llevamos claro. 

No he dicho que sea una obligación. Puedes hacer lo que te de la gana, al fin de cuentas son sólo eso, recomendaciones, que no obligación.

Comment: Lo ideal seria decir por que se recomienda, o por que lo dices, recuerda que los usuarios pueden confundirse, estaria genial que dijeras se recomienda lo siguiente debido a que ... y sustentas la recomendacion

Comment: ¿No crees que nos estariamos saliendo de la pregunta?. Y que si pongo recomieda, es para que indague él por su cuenta, para que luego decida lo que estime más conveniente. 

Su pregunta es muy concreta, quitar el borde negro de la imagen. Está respondida, lo demás incluso podría sobrar. No veo que hayas aportado nada, sólo sarcazmo. Pero en fin...

Comment: Correcto ya es una pregunta respondida, ahora que aportas en tu respuesta que el otro usuario no le halla dicho ?? Para nada fue sarcasmo solo que me causo ruido eso que dijiste. No lo habia escuchado nunca. Saludos cordiales.

Comment: Te pareces mucho al tipico troll que sólo se dedica a señalar y criticar, pero sin aportar nada. Saludos cordiales.